# how to get vimeo api/froogaloop to work on older browsers

Tags: javascript, vimeo, froogaloop

froogaloop is not working on IE 6/7 or Firefox 3.6 using the universal embed code, whats the best way to get it going? detect what the users browser is then output flash embed code or universal embed code?

https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript

http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player-js#examples

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/GFbUu/ here is my updated froogaloop library which supports IE7 (requires jQuery). I'm not sure 'bout IE6, but you can try.